# Why won't this datamapper object save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, datamapper

Here's the model:

```
class Target
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :owed, Integer, :default => 0, :required => true
  property :served, Integer, :default => 0, :required => true

  def go
    @owed -= 1
    @served += 1
    save
  end
end
```

When I do this:

```
t = Target.first
t.go
```

It doesn't seem to update the database.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The resource isn't saving because DataMapper doesn't know that the `owed` and `served` properties have been changed. `#save` will only save the resource, if the resource is considered dirty by DataMapper.

Instead, change the values of `self.owed` and `self.served`, which will cause a state change within the resource, which will mark the resource as dirty and allow `#save` to trigger. Additionally, you can simplify the `go` method using `#update`:

```
def go
  update(:owed => self.owed - 1, :served => self.served + 1)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `self.owed` and `self.served` instead:

```
def go
  self.owed -= 1
  self.served += 1
  save
end
```